# Plotting Soil Water Retention Curve Using van Genuchten Model

Tags: matlab, plot, curve

I'm trying to plot a soil water retention curve using the van Genuchten model in MATLAB.
I have loaded data from an Excel file and applied the model equations. However, I'm facing %issues with fitting the model to the observed theta values and plotting the results. Here's the code:

```matlab
% Load data from Excel file
EV = readtable('Retention.xlsx', 'Sheet', 1);
CB1 = EV(1:38, :);
theta = CB1.SWC_A / 100;  % to change the data in decimale point
h = CB1.psi;
% Parameters obtained from previous experiments
theta_r = 0.070; % Residual water content
theta_s = 0.434; % Saturated water content
alpha = -3.402; % air-entry value
n = 0.3273; % Pore size distribution parameter
m = 3.4195; % Empirical parameter

%Calculate theta_c using the model equation ((van Genuchten model)
theta_c = theta_r + ((theta_s - theta_r) ./ (1 + alpha * abs(h)).^n).^m;

% Fitting the model to the observed theta values (not theta_c)
fitType = fittype('a * (x^b)');
fitOptions = fitoptions(fitType);
fitOptions.StartPoint = [1 1];
fittedModel = fit(h, theta, fitType, fitOptions);`

% Calculate fitted theta values using the fitted model
fittedTheta = fittedModel(h);

%Plotting
figure;
hold on;
scatter(h, theta, 'filled', 'DisplayName', 'Data');
plot(h, fittedTheta, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 1); % Fitted curve
xlabel('Pressure Head (h)');
ylabel('Volumetric Moisture Content (\theta)');
legend('Location', 'SouthEast');
box on;%%%
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG5pz.png]

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data is not ordered, so when you re-use the coarse `h` values for your x-axis, it's actually going back and forth randomly. It doesn't matter for the scatter plot, but not what we want for drawing lines.

The point of fitting a curve is that we not have an analytical function free from the sampling, so, why use the coarse scattered x-axis values at all?
You can just create a linear space of new values for plotting `fittedModel`

```matlab
h_smooth = linspace(min(h), max(h), 1000);  % for a nice smooth plot
fittedTheta = fittedModel(h_smooth);

figure;
hold on;
scatter(h, theta, 'filled', 'DisplayName', 'Data');
plot(h_smooth, fittedTheta, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 1);
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is working. I can also order the y-axis values for the scatter pot?

Comment: @Asegidew You can reorder the scattered data whoever you like as long as you use the same reordering for both the experimental `h`  and `theta`, but there s no reason to bother. Being free to use a different `h` for your analytical function is half the reason for doing this at all.

Comment: I should also mention that a power law doesn't seem to be a good fit for this data: it doesn't seem to approach zero. Maybe `a * (x^b) + c`.